# DataGridView with CheckBox cell problem

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a DataGridView with a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column, which is databound to a list. The problem is that the databound boolean property for this checkbox is updated not when the check box is checked/unchecked, but after the CellLeave event in other words after the cell looses focus. I want this property to be updated right after the check/uncheck. There's an event CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged which is fired right after check/uncheck happens, so I can use it to update the propery manually. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can listen for the [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx) event and force Commit the change:

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(VS.95).aspx

Comment: yes, if you note the msdn documentation is for silverlight. I haven't actually used it myself yet, but there are some examples out there on google.