# Datagridview checkboxcolumn validation

Tags: c#, vb.net, validation, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

In a **DatagridView** I have **databound checkboxcolumns**. But if I check or uncheck multiple checkboxes, not all changes are saved. (It doesn't trigger the property Set method on all, maybe on every 2nd). However if I after each checkbox-click, click on another cell (column) before the next checkbox, then all actions will trigger the Set methods.  So it seems the cell validation does not work on a per-cell basis, but on a per column basis (For the checkboxcolumn).  So how do you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer: [DataGridView with CheckBox cell problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000708/datagridview-with-checkbox-cell-problem)

But probably easier alternative is to put in the save button method:

```
DataGridView.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you have tried and what doesn't work. I assume you have a Winform application and use a SqlDataSource to bind a SQL-Server table to your grid. There is a boolean(bit) field in your database, hence the grid automatically generates a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. You are trying to save all changes that the user has made when he clicks a save-button.

Are all of these guesses correct?

All you have to do is to update your dataset/datatable with the dataadapter.

```
Private Sub BtnSaveChanges_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSaveChanges.Click
    Me.FooTableAdapter.Update(DataSet1.Foo)
End Sub
```

MSD-Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-use/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

If changes should be saved directly to the database, you can handle the [CurrentItemChanged-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.currentitemchanged.aspx) of the BindingSource.

```
Private Sub FooBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FooBindingSource.CurrentItemChanged
     Dim thisDataRow As DataRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, BindingSource).Current, DataRowView).Row
     If thisDataRow.RowState = DataRowState.Modified Then
         Me.FooTableAdapter.Update(thisDataRow)
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought more details was not relevant. But; I'm displaying an object of an entity class (from Linq-to-Sql dbml file), in a datagridview. So the property is a boolean property in this class. I don't autogenerate columns, but I specify with Columns.Add(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn).  The thing is, I put a breakpoint on the Set method of the property (in dbml file), so I notice when it is called. The problem is if you click two checkboxes just after eachother. Only the set method of one of them (the first one) is called, while visually in the datagridview, both actions cause check-mark.

Comment: Sorry I didn't confirm exactly all your questions:  It's a Winforms application, Sql Server Express datasource. I have a save button on a bindingnavigator that calls the repository for saving to the database. But I believe the problem is not really related to the sql/database issue. But simply the way any boolean property is updated by a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. (At least it seems so to me)

Comment: A bit clearer description:  If I have 5 empty checkboxes, then checking all of them, and after last one hit the save button. The "last" checkbox will NOT be saved as checked. If however between the last checkbox and the savebutton, I click on another cell (other column or any checkbox cell outside the exact checkbox square) then this last check will also be part of the save.  So the problem is that the property is not called when the box is being checked, but on the NEXT action on the DataGridView. If however the next action is OUTSIDE that control, the check will not be saved.